# Declaring spatial points as reals instead of integers

Tags: pointers, fortran

I have tried to demonstrate below in the sample code what I am trying to do. I have a bunch of if/else conditions and I want to properly enter them when I compile and run the code.  However I will not enter the ones where i,j is a real number since i,j is defined as an integer in the beginning of the code.  How can I model this problem differently so that I can enter those if/else conditions? Thanks

Specifically, I do not want the spatial points, i,j to be integers.  Instead I want them to be real values that correspond to any position in space, for ex: (x,y) = (5.31, 5.31).

```
program sample

integer :: i,j !spatial points
real, parameter :: DeltaX = 0.1
integer, parameter :: n = 10
real, dimension(-n:n, -n:n) :: u,f

do j = -n,n
do i = -n,n

   f(i,j) = sin(i*DeltaX+j*DeltaX)

end do
end do

do i = -n+1,n-1 !this loop is only over integers
do j = -n+1,n-1 !this loop is only over integers

  if (i == 6 .AND. j == 6 .AND. i == j) then  

    PRINT*, 'i,j', i,j

    u(i,j) = (f(i+1,j+1)+f(i-1,j-1)-f(i,j))/DeltaX**2

  else if ( i == 8 .AND. j == 8. .AND. i == j) then 

    PRINT*, 'i,j ', i,j

    u(i,j) = (f(i+1,j+1)+f(i-1,j-1)-f(i,j))/DeltaX**2

  else if ( i == 5.31 .AND. j == 5.31 .AND. i == j) then 

    PRINT*, 'i,j = ', i,j !I will never enter this if statement though

    u(i,j) = (f(i+1,j+1)+f(i-1,j-1)-f(i,j))/DeltaX**2

  else if ( i == -6.87 .AND. j == -6.87 .AND. i == j) then 

    PRINT*, 'i,j = ', i,j !I will never enter this if statement either

    u(i,j) = (f(i+1,j+1)+f(i-1,j-1)-f(i,j))/DeltaX**2

  else 

   u(i,j) = (f(i+1,j)+f(i-1,j)+f(i,j+1)+f(i,j-1)-4*f(i,j))/DeltaX**2

  end if

end do
end do

end program
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you saying you want to enter the if branch that currently has `i==5.31`? What condition would you like to enter this branch under?

Comment: @Ross Yes exactly.  I want to enter the if branch when i = 5.31 and when j = 5.31 and when i = j; that is the condition.  That is, for the value i,j = 5.31, I want to impose a specific condition on u.

Comment: But, as you note, that will never occur. `i` is given the value of `1`, then `2`, and so on. Also, your goal seems to be to set `u(5.31,5.31)`, which cannot exist.
I think we could help you better if you described *why* you are trying to accomplish this.

Comment: @Ross So how can I define u such that it exists?  I am simply solving a differential equations for all points in space, but for specific random spatial values (ex: x,y = 5.31) I am imposing a different condition on the function.  That is all, theres nothing deeper.

Comment: I think I understand. You shouldn't expect (or require) spatial positions to be integers! Instead, index your grid locations in two dimensions with `i,j` but record the corresponding grid locations as `x(i,j)` and `y(i,j)`. Then `u(i,j)` can be defined anywhere in space.

Comment: Okay, it seems like you definitely understand.  Thanks so much, how can I impose that with code though?  I have been struggling for a few days on it, and I do not know how to really implement what you are saying.  I definitely agree I shouldn't require/expect spatial position to be integers, I just dont know how to fix this problem.

Comment: Play around with it for a while, see what you can find out. I would start by defining `x` and `y` as one-dimensional arrays with your positions (perhaps `DeltaX*i`). Then, in a loop over `i` and `j`, you can start with something like `x_cur = x(i)`, `y_cur=y(j)`. From there, you can play with the value of `u(i,j)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to solve a partial differential equation or some other mathematical problem that emerges by discretizing a continuous equation into a finite set of points. The points are often on an orthogonal grid in the *x* and *y* directions, but a grid can be rotated, skewed, deformed or even completely unstructured. It is useful to remember that as it implies you need something different that you tried.

For structured grids you can use Fortran arrays to store the values of variables in each data point.

```
real ::  u(1:nx,1:ny), f(1:nx, 1:ny)
```

You could do the same for the `x` and `y` coordinates of each point.

For simple orthogonal grids in *x* and *y* you can just use 1D arrays for the `x` and `y` coordinates

```
real :: x(1:nx), y(1:ny)
```

The meaning of these is that every point with given *x* index `i` is at *x*-coordinate `x(i)` and similarly for `y(j)`.

When your computation depends on the coordinates, you can use them simply as

```
do j = 1, ny
  do i = 1, nx
    f(i,j) = func(x(i), y(j))
  end do
end do
```

And for your if statements:

```
do j = 1, ny
  do i = 1, nx
    if (x(i)>something .and. x(i)<something_else) then
      u(i,j) = some_expression with u(i+-1,j+-1) and f(i+-1,j+-1)
    else ...
    end if
  end do
end do
```

Do note that you should *never* compare floating point values (Fortran `real`) for equality like `if (x==5.31)`. Floating point numbers are inexact and `x` can easily be `5.3100000001` instead of `5.31`.

---

You can find countless examples on the internet and even here at Stack Overflow. Just search the web for "Fortran Poisson equation", you will find a huge number of simple code examples for the Jacobi method and other more-elaborate methods too.

Remember that there is a dedicated StackExchange site for Scientific Computation. We could have sent you there straight away, but your first version of the question was very different and not clearly suited for that site.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I have one question, what exactly is the difference between using real,dimension(...) to define u,f opposed to how you defined u,f - just using real :: ...?  I always thought I needed to define arrays using that 'dimension' argument.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691401/array-declaration-in-fortran and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142036/different-syntaxes-to-declare-arrays-with-and-without-the-dimension-statement?noredirect=1

Comment: Thanks, thats helpful!